# Assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast

Tags: c

```
void winner(C_P *wDeck_p, C_IA *wDeck_ia){

    int i, count_p=0, count_ia=0;

    for (i=0; i<2; i++){
        count_p += wDeck_p[i].value;
        count_ia += wDeck_ia[i].value;

        printf("wDeck_p[%d].value =\t%d\n", i, wDeck_p[i].value);
        printf("wDeck_ia[%d].value =\t%d\n", i, wDeck_ia[i].value);

        printf("count_p =\t%d\n", count_p);
        printf("count_ia =\t%d\n", count_ia);
    }

    if (count_p == count_ia)
        printf("EMPATE\n");
    if (count_p>count_ia)
        printf("El jugador ha ganado la ronda\n");
    else
        printf("El jugador ha perdido la ronda\n");
}
```

El código anterior es una función de mi programa, lo que pretende hacer esta función es dados dos arreglos de estructuras (Estructuras definidas como `C_P` y `C_IA`, ambas contienen una variable tipo entero) quiero ver cual suma de los correspondientes elementos de los arreglos de las estructuras de la variable tipo `int` es mayor.

Para tener una mejor claridad de lo que es el programa principal, es un juego de cartas *BlackJack*, apenas voy con el *deal* inicial de 2 cartas y quiero ver cual mazo de cartas es mayor, si el del jugador (`wDeck_p`) o el de la computadora (`wDeck_ia`), también un dato importante es que estoy considerando cada carta como una estructura que contiene el tipo de carta, el valor de la carta en cadena de caracteres y su valor numérico, ahora mismo solo estoy trabajando con los valores numéricos.

El error radica en que como se ve en el ciclo `for`, los valores `wDeck_p[i].value` y `wDeck_ia[i].value` se están imprimiendo correctamente, sin embargo, el problema radica en que las variables `count_p` y `count_ia`, al momento de realizar la suma en el segundo ciclo cuando i=1 guardan datos que no deberían, algo está mal en la suma del contador en el segundo ciclo, sin embargo, como dije, la impresión de los valores que se deben sumar están bien, el error está al efectuar la suma, espero haberme explicado bien, gracias.

Comment: ¿Podrías presentar un ejemplo mínimo y completo que verifique el error?

Comment: No es posible que falle la suma. Deberias mostrar mas informacion, por ejemplo como guardas los valores en los arreglos y tus clases